# How to create a local notifications in Android and iOS with AIR

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

Is there a way to send a local notification with AIR in iOS and Android? I don't see any API but maybe there is a ANE? I think Android supports Alarm Intents. That would work as well.

Comment: There are two listed on this page:  One for iOS and one for Android http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html